# Can someone identify this insect?

Tags: species-identification, species

I photographed this wasp like insect on a buttercup in my wildlife garden.  It can be no longer than 10-15mm.  The bands appear green rather than yellow but I suspect that might be due to the lighting. [image]

Comment: Where are you located? Thanks.

Comment: Lincolnshire UK

Comment: I can't answer because I can't identify it positively, but I think it's a small paper wasp (there are 200 species worldwide.) Some of them are slender and very small with long wings like yours. A side view would be necessary for proper ID, by me at least!

Comment: Thanks for giving me a steer, I'll look at that group

Answer (score 2):

Having looked through Steven Falk's amazing collection of photos, I'm now thinking its one of the Stem Boring Sawflies, most likely Cephus spinipes, a Grass Stem Borer, which Steven Falk calls the Timothy Stem Borer.

To quote his site "C. spinipes is one of our commonest cephids and is recorded widely as far north as Yorkshire in a variety of grassy habitats. The rather maggot-like, whitish larvae develop in the stems of grasses such as Timothy. Adults fly from May to July and can be numerous on buttercup flowers."

https://flic.kr/s/aHsmsWKR4q